# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How could a US Senator be prevented from reading classified information into the record?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/how-could-a-us-senator-be-prevented-from-reading-classified-information-into-the)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What does it mean to send a resolution "over, under the rule"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/what-does-it-mean-to-send-a-resolution-over-under-the-rule)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can the POTUS neuter "advice and consent" by refusing to delegate?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/can-the-potus-neuter-advice-and-consent-by-refusing-to-delegate)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are the OECD, IMF and the WTO really relevant organizations and what is the price for a country to ignore them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/are-the-oecd-imf-and-the-wto-really-relevant-organizations-and-what-is-the-pric)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Has Japan's "Special Secrecy Law" been condemned by the United Nations?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/has-japans-special-secrecy-law-been-condemned-by-the-united-nations)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [When and why did the President of the French Republic inherit the titles of the King of France?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/when-and-why-did-the-president-of-the-french-republic-inherit-the-titles-of-the)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why do Iran and Saudi Arabia share the same "age of majority"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/why-do-iran-and-saudi-arabia-share-the-same-age-of-majority)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Is there separation of religion and state in Canada?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/is-there-separation-of-religion-and-state-in-canada)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Nationally-mandated term limits for mayors?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6520/nationally-mandated-term-limits-for-mayors)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Population size and the viability of democracy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6522/population-size-and-the-viability-of-democracy)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---